# java; How to get the Variable Outside of the Action Listener?

Tags: java

NOTE: My english isn't the best So please don't mind too much Grammar mistakes.

Hey there, java Beginner here, Anyways i was coding my CPS Tester Program, Just as a first mini Program. Anyways, This question may have been asked before but,
I need get a variable Outside a ActionListener code:

```
public static void startB() {
 Font f = new Font(null, Font.BOLD , 0);

    Font size = f.deriveFont(20f);

    JLabel text = new JLabel("");
    text.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(250,250));
    text.setFont(size);

    JButton b = new JButton();
    JFrame cps = new JFrame("CLICK");
    cps.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400,400));
    cps.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    cps.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    b.setText("<html> CLICK ME <br> As much as you can! <html> ");
    cps.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    cps.getContentPane().add(b , BorderLayout.CENTER);
    cps.getContentPane().add(text, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    cps.pack();
    cps.setVisible(true);

    text.setText("<html> Starting in... <br> 3<html>");
    try {
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep((long)1.0);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    text.setText("<html> Starting in... <br> 2<html>");
    try {
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep((long)1.0);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    text.setText("<html> Starting in... <br> 1<html>");
    try {
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep((long)1.0);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    text.setText("<html> CLICK! <html>");
    b.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            double clicks = 0;
            clicks++;
            // How to get Clicks variable out of the actionListener?
        }
    });
    try {
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep((long)10.0);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    //I need get the Clicks Variable to here.
}
```

If you can help me Please respond to the post. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Here you create a anonymous class of `ActionListener` :

```
b.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    double clicks = 0;
    clicks++;
        // How to get Clicks variable out of the actionListener?

    }
  });
```

And you declared the `clicks` variable inside it.
You could declare `clicks` in the outer class but it will not work as the compiler expects that `clicks` be `final`. Which is not compatible with your usage of it : you mutate it inside `actionPerformed()`.

An alternative to achieve your need is creating a non anonymous implementation of `ActionListener` where you will store  `clicks` as a field and provide a getter to retrieve the value of it.

It could be an inner class :

```
private static class MyActionListener implements ActionListener {

    private double clicks;

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        clicks++;
    }

    public double getClicks() {
        return clicks;
    }

}
```

And you could use it in this way :

```
MyActionListener actionListener = new MyActionListener();
myComponent.addActionListener(actionListener);
...
// later retrieve clicks
double clicks = actionListener.getClicks();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can only access `final` variables of your outer class in an anonymous inner class. But as the modifier `final` suggests the value of such a variable can't be changed anymore once assigned.

To circumvent this you could use an `AtomicInteger` instead of a plain `int` or `double` to store the clicks and declare this `final` variable outside of your action listener:

```
final AtomicInteger clicks = new AtomicInteger(0);
b.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        clicks.incrementAndGet();
    }
}
clicks.get(); // will return the desired number of invocations of actionPerformed
```

This way you can still use an anonymous class for your action listener.

It would be better though - from a code style perspective - to define a named class and provide a getter for the click count as suggested in the other answer.

Comment: @davidxxx I just provided an answer to the question and already mentioned, that it is not the best way of doing it.

Comment: Ah sorry I bad read. I understood the contrary. It is fine as alternative with this warning.